# change the folder (app) in nextjs app-router

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js, next.js13

hello I want to rename  default app-router folder (app) in nextjs

I search but I do not find any solution

I want  to change it like this :
src/app/layout.tsx
to
src/nextapp/layout.tsx

how can I do it ?? any body know it to learn me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot rename the app folder as it can cause potential issues with routing within your nextjs application.

Please refer the Routing Doc : [App Routing in NextJS](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing)

There are a set of special files in Routing apart from pages.ts. Your application will not be able find these files if you try to rename your **src/app** to **src/next-app**.